# Presento este problema en mi proyecto Laravel Undefined offset: 0 (View:

Tags: laravel, offset

Este modulo de grupos, no me permite editar, al momento de clickear en edit aparece

```
Undefined offset: 0 (View: /home/u919130904/domains/agape.org.co/public_html/gacl/resources/views/groups/edit.blade.php)
```

Mi código:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('breadcrumbs', Breadcrumbs::render('groups.edit'))

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Actualizar Grupo</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            @if (session('message'))
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
                    </button>
                    {{ session('message') }}
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-left">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card shadow-sm">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('groups.update', $group->id) }}">
                        @method('PUT')
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Nombre *</label>
                            <input
                                id="name"
                                name="name"
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Nombre" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
                                value="{{ $group->name }}"
                                class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                            >
                            @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Un saludo.